# techtalk specflow assist dynamic instance exception

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have been developing an automation framework using selenium,c#, and specflow, for speflow I only created one scenario of login yet but I am getting an exception of **techtalk.specflow.assist.dynamicinstancefromtable.exception**. This error I am getting when I am trying to retrieve UserName and Password from the feature file by using Dynamicinstance(). I will share snippets of my code so maybe you can help me. And I am sorry as I am new to this so if anything more required for the answer please do let me know.

**Code Snippet**

```
Feature: Login
Check if the login functionality
is working as expected with different permutations and
combinations of data

Background: 
#Given i delete employee 'Autouser' before i start running test

@unit @positive
Scenario: Check login with correct username and password
Given I have navigated to the application
And I see application open
When I enter UserName and Password
| UserName            |  | Password  |
| ankit1000@gmail.com |  | ankit1000 |
Then I click login button
Then I should see MyAccount page
```

**LoginSteps Class**

```
using com.uli.PageObjects;
using com.uli.TestCases.PageObjects;
using CommonProj.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;
namespace com.uli.StepsDefination
{
[Binding]
public class LoginSteps:BaseSteps
{
    [Given(@"I have navigated to the application")]
    public void GivenIHaveNavigatedToTheApplication()
    {
        NavigateSite();
        CurrentPage = GetInstance<LoginPage>();
    }

    [Given(@"I see application open")]
    public void GivenISeeApplicationopen()
    {
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().CheckIfLoginExist();
    }

    [When(@"I enter UserName and Password")]
    public void WhenIEnterUserNameandPassword(Table table1)
    {
       dynamic data = table1.CreateDynamicInstance();
        //dynamic data = DynamicTableHelpers.CreateDynamicInstance(table);
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>
().PerformLoginCredentials(data.UserName,data.Password);
    }

    [Then(@"I click login button")]

    public void ThenIclickOnLoginButton()
    {
        CurrentPage = CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().PerformLoginBtnClick();
    }

    [Then(@"I should see MyAccount page")]

    public void ThenIshouldSeeMyAccountPage()
    {
        if (CurrentPage.As<MyAccount>().GetLoggedInUser().Contains("My Account"))
            System.Console.WriteLine("Succesful Login");
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine("Unsuccesful login");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Hi JeffC surely i will paste the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty column in your table.

```
When I enter UserName and Password
| UserName            |  | Password  |
| ankit1000@gmail.com |  | ankit1000 |
```

This should be:

```
When I enter UserName and Password
| UserName            | Password  |
| ankit1000@gmail.com | ankit1000 |
```

Empty columns are not valid in Gherkin and so in SpecFlow.

Also:
Please use the reserved TLDs & Domain names for testing: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606
That is the global standard.
Please don't use any other TLDs or Domains in test data! Someone could get unwanted email.

Comment: Hi Andreas, your solution really worked, thank you so much. And yes i will take your advice on TLDs or Domains, it was a negligence from my side. Thanks again